# JSON a XML y XML a JSON C#

Tags: c#, json, api, xml, webservice

soy nuevo en C# y quisiera una ayuda u orientación.
Necesito crear una aplicación de consola que vaya a una ruta de servidor y extraiga los archivos XML que existan en el mismo y que a su vez los convierta en JSON  y los coloque en un WS.
Por otra parte, debe también ir al WS y extraer otros archivos tipo JSON, convertirlos en XML y guardarlos en el servidor anteriormente mencionado pero en una carpeta diferente.

Agradecería la orientación que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Esta pregunta es muy amplia para el formato del sitio.. aca contestamos preguntas concretas.. cual es tu problema concreto?

Comment: Conocer que tipo de librerías usar por ejemplo, para poder realizar lo que describo en la pregunta, hacia donde debo orientarme. No quisiera que me expliquen que hacer, sino hacia donde orientarme en dicho sentido. Ya que soy nuevo en dicha área. Muy agradecido por el interés.

Comment: Esta clase de preguntas, termina cerrada porque no damos ayuda sobre librerias o recursos externos.. google es mucho mejor que nosotros para eso...

Comment: En el mundo de JSON y XML hay muchas opciones, a mi me parece interesante la de XSLT 3.0 con XPath 3.1 que permite procesar tanto XML como JSON; en el contexto del .NET framework lo puedes utilizar con Saxon .NET HE https://www.nuget.org/packages/Saxon-HE/